# Classical solution of Pde's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

How to find a classical solution $u=u(x_{1},u_{2})$ to $$(x_{2}^{2}+u)u_{x_{1}} + x_{2}u_{x_{2}}=0$$ with the initial value $u(x_{2}^{2}/2 , x_{2})=0$.

I worked on this problem but as $g=0$ , I don't know how to find the solution. Please guide me.

Comment: It's a quasi-linear PDE, so you could try the method of caracteristic curves.

Comment: Is it possible to explain more to find the solution because I used this method but since g=0 , I don't obtain the solution. On the other hand, I know this problem has infinitely solution. If you know please write your idea

Comment: In the question, what is $g$ suddenly coming out of nothing ?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the PDE is :
$$\left(y^2+u(x,y)\right)u_x+y\:u_y=0$$
Chapit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{y^2+u}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{0}$$
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

A first characteristic equation comes from $0\:dx=du$
$$u=c_1$$
This was obvious at first sight to the PDE that $u(x,y)=$constant is a characteristic equation.

A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{y^2+c_1}=\frac{dy}{y}$ :
$$y^{c_1}e^{\frac12 y^2-x}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_1=F(c_2)$ is :
$$\boxed{u=F\big(y^{u}e^{\frac12 y^2-x}\big)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.

Condition : $u(\frac12 y^2\:,\:y)=0$

Note that $u(x,y)=$constant is a characteristic equation. This is the present case  with constant$=0$. As we know if the condition is specified on a characteristic curve generaly  there is not an unique solution. So we don't expect a unique solution.

$$u(\frac12 y^2\:,\:y)=0=F\big(y^{0}e^{\frac12 y^2-\frac12 y^2}\big)$$
$$0=F\big(y^{0}e^{\frac12 y^2-\frac12 y^2}\big)$$
$$F(1)=0$$
Thus any function $F(X)$ is convenient if $F(1)=0$

They are an infinity of functions $F(X)$ which are equal to $1$ when $X=1$. Thus they are an infinity of solutions $u(x,y)$.

$$\boxed{u(x,y)=F\big(y^{u(x,y)}e^{\frac12 y^2-x}\big)\qquad \text{with } F(1)=0.}$$

This is an implicit equation. Depending of the kind of function $F$ one can or not solve it analytically for $u$. Choosing some nice functions $F$ allows to express $u(x,y)$ explicitly.